# python - How to read table with chunksize and names

Tags: python, scikit-learn

how can i read data from a csv with chnunksize and names?

I tried this:

```
sms = pd.read_table('demodata.csv', header=None, names=['label', 'good'])
X = sms.label.tolist()
y = sms.good.tolist()
```

and it worked totaly fine. But if try this, i'll get an error:

```
sms = pd.read_table('demodata.csv', chunksize=100, header=None, names=['label', 'good'])
X = sms.label.tolist()
y = sms.good.tolist()
```

And i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e3f35149ab7f> in <module>()
----> 1 X = sms.label.tolist()
      2 y = sms.good.tolist()

AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'label'
```

Why does it work in the first but not in the second place?

Comment: If you set chunksize then `read_table` returns an iterator, not a dataframe. You would have found that out with a simple `print(sms)` or looking at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking). SO is not a [debugging service](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: @FHTMitchell he didn’t do that so add a question on stack overflow

Comment: @FHTMitchell oh yes, now I see my mistake. I thought I would also get a dataframe and didn't think about, that the datatype would change. 
Thanks for your fast reply!